# Using Google Analytics to track tweets and website traffic

Tags: google-analytics

Basically,

my task is to: use Google Analytics data to track the number of tweets R bloggers make per day as well as the incoming traffic from twitter, such that I can generate a csv file and I can perform analysis on these data.

I was given a hint to look at the Google API documentation for info on what data can be scraped using Google Analytics: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#q_summary
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

This is what i am asked to do ultimately. I was so confused. I do not have a clue what approach and how to do this. Do I have to build an application to do this ?

Now, I have never used google analytics  / google developers before. I am **not** looking a solution here. Rather, I am looking for someone who can point me to the right direction, i.e. links or materials to look at in order to tackle this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to track people who come to your site and tweet a blog post, you should be able to get data by installing social interaction tracking:

Google Analytics : [Twitter Tweets](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial#twitter)

Universal Analytics : [Social Interactions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/social-interactions)

Once you have installed social tracking, you can view the social plugins report in Google Analytics by going to Acquisitions > Social > Plugins.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to using google analytics and google api. So, for example if I want to track the number of tweets Rbloggers makes a day, do I track this url ?https://twitter.com/Rbloggers   Because you guys kept talking about "track the traffic on MY website". Does it mean I cannot track social media website ?