# Google Analytics:Failed to add tracking code to a social media website

Tags: twitter, google-analytics

I am new to Google Analytics. Basically, I want to track the number of tweets Rbloggers make per day and its incoming traffic. So, I believe I need to track the following website:

https://twitter.com/Rbloggers

However, when I try to add the Google Analytics tracking code to the web source by selecting "Tools > View Source", I found out that I could not add tracking code to the web source. I have no idea why, because I saw people in youtube videos just add the tracking code with ease.

Then, I observed that many video tutorials and websites talk about adding tracking code to "YOUR" website not a public social media website. Does it mean there is no way I can use Google Analytics to track this site, since this is not "MY" website

https://twitter.com/Rbloggers   ?

Comment: You cannot select tools > view source and add more code there. That's just not how websites work, even ones that you own. What you attempted to do was draw a picture on a piece of paper and tape it to your tv and wonder why it's not IN your tv and also wonder why it's not on everybody else's tv. The short answer is you cannot add your own code to your twitter.com page.

Comment: So, is there any way to track the website above ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: You can use the [Twitter APIs](https://dev.twitter.com/) to get that sort of data. Alternatively, there are a number of 3rd party services such as [TwitterCounter](http://twittercounter.com/) that use the Twitter APIs and provide an interface for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Google Analytics to track tweets and website traffic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288230/using-google-analytics-to-track-tweets-and-website-traffic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of a question you posted 10 hours before this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288230/using-google-analytics-to-track-tweets-and-website-traffic

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way for you to add GA code to a site you don't own (i.e., have access to the server on which the site is hosted). If you want to know how many visits are coming from the links you post, you can look in the Acquisition -> Social -> Overview reports. You can also add campaign codes to the links you tweet - you can find more info here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en